# How to trim all whitespace from string, but preserve a single trailing line break if one exists

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple php function to behave the same as the php `trim()` function, except that it preserves a single trailing line break if one exists.  In addition, it needs to support preserving CRLF, CR and LF cases.

Consider the following use cases:

1. `myTrim(`" \t  \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t  \t "`)` === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
2. `myTrim(`" \t  \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t  \r\n\r\n \t \r\n "`)` === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r\n"
3. `myTrim(`" \t  \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t  \r\r \t \r "`)` === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r"
4. `myTrim(`" \t  \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t  \n\n \t \n "`)` === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"

I have unsuccessfully tried a function such as:

```
public static function trimMessageBlock( $block )
{
    // Remove all leading whitespace (e.g. HT (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32))
    $block = preg_replace("/^\s+/", "", $block);
    // Remove all trailing whitespace, but preserve a single trailing line break if one exists
    $block = preg_replace("/\s*(\R?)\s*$/", "$1", $block);

    return $block;
}
```

The above code seems to ignore the line break character entirely, and match only the simple case (`\s*`).  The only other way I can see to do this is to use a "if" statement to test for a `/\s*\R\s*$/` pattern first, then either use `/\s*\R\s*$/` or `/\s+$/`, depending on if a newline is present of not. Any suggestions on a simpler, more elegant way to do this in regex?

*BTW This is my first post to stackoverflow*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it something like this. *(see comments)*

```
<?php

function myTrim($str) {
    //Look for a non whitespace character with whitespace following.
    //Capture the first (either 1 or 2) consecutive line ending characters
    if (preg_match("/[^\s]\s*?(\R)\s*$/", $str, $capture)) {
        // return the trimmed string, plus the line break
        return trim($str) . $capture[1];
    }
    //No line endings were found
    return trim($str);
}

var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \t ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\n\r\n \t \r\n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r\n");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\r \t \r ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \n\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");
//Added a couple more edge test cases
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \n\r\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\n\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r\n");

//Outputs
//bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
```

Comment: Great, I like your approach, but your function can be simplified using "\R" rather than "[\r\n]"

Comment: @Talisphere Perfect. All tests still pass. I didn't realise \R matched \r\n too. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified...

```
function myTrim($str) {
    // if trailing line break exists, preserve it
    if ( preg_match("/\s*?(\R)\s*$/", $str, $capture) ) {
        // return the trimmed string, plus the line break
        return trim($str) . $capture[1];
    }

    // No line break was found, return the trimmed string
    return trim($str);
}

var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \t ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\n\r\n \t \r\n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r\n");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\r \t \r ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \n\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");
//Added a couple more edge test cases
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \n\r\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n");
var_dump(myTrim(" \t \r\n The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog \t \r\n\n \t \n ") === "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\r\n");
```